# China using gunpowder to take over Europe in the 1200s?

Tags: technology

This is my first question, I hope this is the right place for it.

In real life, would Chinese cannon (before Europe had anything better than bows) have been an insurmountable advantage if China had indeed decided to attack the West or were cannon too unreliable or ineffective to have made much difference?

There is also the possibility that the Europeans could have copied the weapons but: making gunpowder is not completely trivial (there is a process of making grains the right size) and manufacturing cannon is also non-trivial since the metal must be of a certain quality, etc.

Comment: During what time period are you asking about? Do they attack by land or by sea? What size would the invading force be? Would Europe have any warning, or is it a surprise attack?

Comment: sorry, i forget to mention century.

Comment: even with the century, you lack crucial information, also including logistics. Also note: the most simple cannon is a log of wood, drilled out. They can be used a couple times before being junk, but are REAL easy to make.

Comment: I am only saying, given the gunpowder advantage -- it would be up to the Chinese to decide the most effective usage and if land or sea distances presented problems, that would be part of the answer.

Comment: the title says Europe.

Comment: Fundamentally, this seems a classic "*What-if-I-introduced-superweapon-X?*" question. The answer is always "*the enemy adapts*". The far-western barbarians will figure out that the boom-sticks are less effective in the rain and at night, and take time to arm, and will adapt their tactics accordingly.

Comment: VTC:Needs-Details. We need *specifics.* For example, [The earliest European references to gunpowder are found in Roger Bacon's Opus Majus from 1267](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_cannon), so after 1267 the answer is certainly "no." 1150-1250 was a period of *very rapid* development in canon technology, so exactly which canon/firearm are you talking about? We need at least an exact year and an exact target country. (And I'm still convinced the logistics of the distances involved make the question moot.)

Comment: @JBH: let's say before Europeans knew of gunpowder. They would have learned of it when the first attack happened but learning how to then make it and cannon would have given China probably years of being the only side with cannon.

Comment: @releseabe  I strongly recommend you take the time to [read about the history of gunpowder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_gunpowder). Europe's first recorded use of it, as mentioned was in 1267. But at that time mobile canon (the way you're thinking about them) [didn't exist, even in China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_cannon). The history of firearms like that was incredibly fluid and developed incredibly fast. There might not be a time when the question you want answered actually makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

Even with overwhelming military advantage, "world conquest" is anything but simple. Their cannons could be wonders of the medieval world and allow them to win every single conflict they take part in, and China could still easily lose (I forget what dynasty this even is in the 1200s).

There's the old saw about tactics, strategy, and logistics. And it might be groan-worthy, but it is nonetheless true. How many soldiers can't China move through to Europe? How does it feed them? How does it rotate them out? How do these men stay loyal to the regime back home, when every European monarch is offering bribes that are large fortunes, or even their own little fiefdoms?

What happens when Europe adopts tactics that aren't easily punished with cannons? Guerilla insurgencies? Murdering collaborators gruesomely, so that no locals cooperate? Do they make the gunpowder locally (thus allowing Europeans to possibly steal the secrets), or ship it from home with a 5-year-long supply line?

While it's not inconceivable that this could lead to Chinese victory and Sinitization of Europe in the 1200s, it's not clear that if all the hurdles could be crossed that it wouldn't also be possible *without the cannons*. I think this is all very implausible, but that it does not become any more plausible with that slight tactical advantage.

Comment: It was quite an ordeal for the English to send their armies to France and keep them supplied, only ~100 miles away.  China is ~5000 miles away.

Comment: Chinese managed to send a force all the way to the middle of Asia and beat up the local power in Han Dynasty--the War of Heavenly Horses. The only reason the lost in manpower is due to corruption and incompetence in the generals. So if assuming that none of this corruption and incompetence happens, then I don't think it is too much that a Chinese force can go and give the European Kings some greeting

Comment: @FaitoDayo A far longer and more distant engagement just has more "surface area" for corruption/incompetence not less. Your statement is basically the equivalent of "assume a spherical, frictionless cow with a mass of one proton".

Comment: The corruption happens because a favored concubine asked the emperor to let her brother to take command of the expedition army so the brother can be promoted. If situation is different, the emperor could be more smart about the employment of personnel and the generals in charge could be a competent one instead--they do exist, just to remind you. And Mongols can reach Europe too, are they corrupted?

Comment: @FaitoDayo Corruption happens because humans are corruptible, and certain regime styles tend to be less effective in discouraging it. Once it flourishes though, it never really goes away, for too many underlings have essentially been trained in the methods and processes of corruption. This wasn't a "one-off", it was endemic.

Answer (score 5):

China taking over Europe in the 1200s...

Hmm.

In the 1200s there was this gentleman named [Genghis Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genghis_Khan) who built himself an empire and did his best to take over **both** Europe and China.

So, you see, in the 1200s the Chinese were quite busy gallantly trying (in vain) to *defend themselves* against the Mongols. They had no time to think about taking over distant lands of which they had only a very vague idea.

In the end, the Mongols failed to take over Europe, not that they put a lot of effort into it. But in the second half of the 13th century (1271 to be specific), Genghis Khan's grandson, the famous [Kubla Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kublai_Khan), did take China (plus Tibet and Korea), and became the first emperor of the [Yuan dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Yuan_emperors).

> *[In Xanadu did Kubla Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubla_Khan) a stately pleasure-dome decree: where Alph, the sacred river, ran through caverns measureless to man down to a sunless sea.*

1. The Mongols [did actually use gunpowder weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_gunpowder#Use_by_the_Mongols) in the 13th century. All direct references to such weapons are from the Chinese theater, or maybe should we say the Eastern Front; but it is quite possible they also used them on a smaller scale on the European theater.
2. At that time, Europe was a poor and barbarian backwater. The splendiferous Chinese empire would have had no incentive to take it over, ...
3. Especially because the only open route between China and Europe was overland. The Arabs had closed the sea route about half a millennium earlier.

Comment: @releseabe: No "the British" did not destroy the Indian boatmaking industry. Not in any reasonable sense. (And the Indians did not have "advanced ships" for any reasonable meaning of the word "advanced". Or else we would be hard pressed to explain how come that the *tiny* European naval forces rampaged around unopposed. It's not as if in the 16th, 17th and 18th century European powers had the capability to project great force across the world. Asian navies, even when they existed, were hundreds of years out of date.) (And the British *did* set up shipbuilding yards in India.)

Comment: @releseabe The "indian" shipbuilding industry did not exist until the British, Portoguese and Hollandians started to build their east Indiamen there

Comment: @Trish: ask someone from India about that. India had rockets better than those of the British also.

Comment: @releseabe: Well, the British did not have any rockets whatsoever, unless you are speaking about signal flares...

Comment: so india has rockets that were effective which i believe british copied.

Comment: @releseabe: You don't think those people from India might perhaps be just a little bit biased?  If there were advanced Indian ships, where did they go?  Unless I'm completely mistaken (which is possible, since I certainly don't claim to be an expert on the subject), European trade with India was always European ships going to India, not Indian ships coming to Europe.

Comment: @jamesqf: yes, they might be but that is nothing compared to the western bias in usa and i assume european textbooks. i believe we are discovering a lot of mathematics being done earlier in india/china/middle east before the europeans discovered it. so i do believe it is at least possible that india was more advanced in some areas than england was; i know that china did have goods that could not be made in england at the end of the 1700s. so again, it is possible that asian countries had some things that england did not,

Comment: The kingdom of Mysore did have rockets which were impressive enough to catch the eye of the British, and they [did in fact improve on them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congreve_rocket#Early_Indian_rockets)... after conquering Mysore in two wars spanning a total of about five years. So while the rockets were effective, they weren't apparently *that* effective. The British tried long and hard to make Congreves the next big thing, but they were never effective enough to displace other weapons.

Comment: @Cadence: It is interesting how often a new technology that eventually dominates initially was so buggy it was ignored for sometimes decades. And bugs are not the only problem: in the 1820s or so some guy developed a steam-powered carriage. No tracks, basically an automobile that worked well enough to be used in a service. But horse-drawn carriage services lobbied against this and managed to stop the service. And even this had a predecessor by maybe 50 years although it was impractical due to I guess old-fashioned (by 1820s standards) steam engine.

Comment: @releseabe To be sure, early technology usually has a lot of drawbacks. But (to circle back to the point) Chinese gunpowder weaponry was very much in that stage of development at this time. It had a long way to go before it could decide battles on its own.

Comment: @Cadence Tangentially related is the invention of an air rifle -- i would have guessed that that occurred 19th century but it is a 17th century invention and when there was no such thing as a repeating gunpowder rifle, Lewis and Clark had one that could fire 30 times in a row -- you'd've thought those would be very popular but while they were used in warfare, there were a variety of reasons why they did not replace single-shot muzzle loaders although I did not find the reasons very compelling compared to a weapon that did not even require gunpowder.

Comment: @AlexP  The Mongols did take over a large percentage of Europe, depending on exactly where one thinks the the eastern border of Europe is.  They made Georgia their vassal, as well as most of European Russia, Belarus, the Ukraine, Bulgaria, etc.  Their armies also penetrated much farther west than those countries

Comment: @M.A.Golding: I'm a Romanian... Genghis Khan's Mongols *did not* take Bulgaria, if by Bulgaria you mean the modern state of that name. They did take over parts of Russia. They held the territory of modern Byelorussia and the northern part of what is today called Ukraine (including Kiev) only for a very short span of time. The ex-Mongol Tartars held the southern part of modern Ukraine well into the modern age -- Russia got control over it only in the 18th century. (And wherever the boundary between Europe and Asia is, it is always north of Georgia; Georgia is firmly in Asia.)

Comment: @releseabe: But math is not the same as shipbuilding.  I don't doubt that India (and China, Japan, &c) were, and still are, more advanced than European countries in some areas - just look at the things the West has adopted from them.  I'm just saying that I've seen no evidence that shipbuilding or maritime travel was one of them.

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean "What if"??

In the 1200's, the owners of China (the mongols under Ghengis khan) DID invade Europe.

And yes, they DID use gunpowder weapons.
(Catapult-fired gunpowder bombs,
gunpowder hand-mortars called [Huochong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongol_conquest_of_China)
and occasionally for city sieges a larger gunpowder stone-throwing mortar)

And yes, they were quite successful

Largest Empire the World has ever seen, the historians say.

Answer (score 1):

If China had decided to attack Europe, cannon would have a negligible factor.

First off, they would have to travel by land.  Silk still traveled by the Silk Road because sea travel was infeasible, despite the enormous duties imposed by the countries it traveled through.  The army would have to cross very inhospitable lands -- desert, mountain, steppe.

Supplies would be another major issue.  Those lands are also not noted for their vast amounts of food.

Cannon would be a heavy thing they had to lug, and they would need to lug their gunpowder as well, or figure out ways to manufacture it in Europe, so it might easily be a hinderance rather than an aid.

Answer (score 0):

### Chinese firearms were not game changer weapons

The 1st firearm was the fire lance which were only effective at ranges up to about 3m and were used right before a melee to disrupt enemy lines.  Much like the Roman Plumbata, they were effective at what they did, but rarely made or broke the outcome of a whole battle. Other than that they had a sort of primitive hand grenade which were comparable at best to the Greek Fire grenades already being used by the Byzantines, they had rockets which were too inaccurate for most uses, and then they had artillery cannons which were great in a siege, but not so much of a battlefield weapon.

The inventions that took gunpowder and turned it into a replacement for traditional weapons mostly happen in Europe/the Middle East or they happened almost simultaneously with no clear way to prove who invented what 1st.

The first practical style of firearm was the European Handgonne or the Chinese Huochong.  When these weapons were invented however is somewhat debatable. In the West they first appeared some time between 1260 and 1365 whereas in China, they first appeared between 1128 and 1288.  This first pictorial evidence of this style of firearm is from about 1128 in China, but this evidence is often discredited as probably being a fire lance since they look so similar and no literary or archaeological evidence supports the existence of Huochongs at that time.  The first literary evidence comes from a written account of the 1260 Battle of Ain Jalut in Egypt, but some historians believe that this is a mistranslation and that the weapon being used was actually some manner of flame thrower.  So, depending on who is correct, the western world will either already have comparable weapons to the Chinese, or they will not be far behind.

To further complicate the Handgonne/Huochongs debate, these weapons on their own could not actually compete with the European Longbow or the Asian composite bow in most contexts.  These early guns had an effective range no longer than their archery counterparts and a much lower rate of fire and accuracy... not to mention their tendency to maim their own user from overpacking, material defects, or uncleared cinders.  So they remained a specialist weapon at best until about 1420 when the Hussites decided to pair them with War Wagons in Europe.  These war wagons allowed them to draw knights in close enough to use the Handgonnes to fire on knights overcoming their armor without exposing themselves enough to be overrun by them.

Meanwhile in the Eastern World, firearms did not begin to become a prominent weapon until the mid-1300s; however, its superiority over traditional warfare was not really well establishing until the 1500s when the Portuguese introduced them to technologies like bored gun barrels and matchlock firing mechanisms.  Between the 1300s and 1500s, Chinese armies using Huochongs were often outmatched by traditional weapons.

In summation, since gunpowder did not really give the Chinese a significant advantage over traditional weapons in their own hemisphere while fighting enemies like the Mongols, it is unlikely they would have made a difference in Europe in the 1200s (before they were even a commonly used weapon China anyway).

Comment: That's helpful. I know that bows were used in Europe for many years because of limitations of firearms. Weaponizing gunpowder is non-trivial -- there had been nothing like the power of explosives prior to gunpowder. The idea of why a spinning projectile is more accurate was not understood, I don't think, before Newton and causing this via rifling is a hard manufacturing problem. Still, gunpowder would have been an advantage of some sort, maybe not enough to overcome Europe -- or maybe even without gunpowder China could have effective invaded if they had desired it.

Comment: The rocket artillery? Korean invention.

Comment: "Fire Lances" were 10th century.    For 13th century, as OP wants, you are looking more at catapult-hurled gunpowder bombs, gunpowder hand cannons (Huochong), and larger gunpowder mortars firing rock projectiles.

Comment: And no, in the 1200's Chinese China could not have invaded Europe. They were being kept quite busy being invaded by Mongol China! Actually, more like they had been successfully invaded, and were busy trying to assimilate the enemy.

Comment: @MarvinKitfox Oops, I read the question wrong as 12th century, not 1200s. I will revise the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are good, but I'd like to add some.

The biggest challenge of making an explosive gunpowder into a modern-like firearm was steel strength. Soft metal known to China back at a time could not be used in making firearms, since it could not sustain gunpowder explosions. Cannons that would explode themselves would make a very poor ones.

In Europe, however, such metal was known, as it was developed and perfected for church bells. These bells were made to sustain high repetitive impact for a long time. It made just perfect for firearms once the gunpowder became known in Europe.

It was due to the lack of proper materials in China that proper cannons were never developed.

Comment: China mostly used bronze for their early firearms.  Bronze was sometimes used in Europe too up until  the late 1700s. European iron cannons were much cheaper to mass produce, but heavier than their bronze counterparts.